# using colab and windows 10, and chrome version 64b , and chrome driver 32b , i changed all path options, but result are the same as below

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
import os
from linkedin_scraper import Person, actions
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Chrome("/content/chromedriver.exe", options=chrome_options)
```

WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver.exe' executable may have wrong permissions. Please
see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home

Comment: The permission error might be because the path is wrong here. Try to put in the full .exe path in the webdriver.Chrome(...) call argument